# How to use fontspec with palatino package?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am trying to typeset a book in Palatino with a custom font, Rockwell, used for headings. I can easily set the book in Palatino by using the `palatino` package, if I use the `fontspec` package to import my Rockwell files, all the body text reverts to default. I tried importing a TTF version of Palatino using `fontspec` but the result was uglier than the version that comes with the Palatino package.

Basically:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Rockwell}
\setmainfont{Palatino}

\begin{document}
This text should be in Palatino.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to change the font only for headings, e.g. chapter titles?

Comment: Yes, I want chapter titles to be in Rockwell and everything else to be Palatino.

Comment: Whay don't you use TeX Gyre Pagella, which a Palatino clone, which exists in .otf format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the `scrbook` class to change the heading font easily:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}%% The Palatino from the TeX Gyre Project
\newfontfamily\headingfont{RockwellStd}%% I have only the RockwellStd.otf
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\headingfont}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{foo}
    \section{bar}
    This text should be in Palatino.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but now ```` and `''` don't render as quotation marks. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @JohnAllie Add `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` before setting your  fonts.

Comment: @JohnAllie: That should be the default. Which TeX distribution you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The `palatino` package uses the legacy New Font Selection Scheme to select an 8-bit font.  To select (a clone of) Palatino as your main font with `fontspec`, use

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0]
```

On most installations, the `palatino` package will also get you TeX Gyre Pagella, but with support for fewer characters.  I’m not sure where your `Palatino.ttf` came from, but it might be an older version from Adobe.

Note that, if you genuinely wanted to combine Unicode and legacy 8-bit encodings, you would not load both `palatino` and `fontspec`.  You would give `\setmainfont` the option `NFSSFamily=qpl` to load Pagella when you switch beck to a legacy encoding such as T1.

If you have Rockwell on your system, you probably installed Microsoft Office and therefore also have a genuine version of Palatino.  That lets you write

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}[Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}]
```

Apple also distributes a genuine Palatino with its iWork.  On a Mac, check your Font Book for Palatino.

You could also use `\IfFontExistsTF` to load the real thing if you have it, and fall back to the clone if not.  You might not want this, as your document would then produce different output if compiled on different installations.

```
\IfFontExistsTF{Palatino Linotype}%
  {\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}[
    Scale=1.0,
    Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}]}%
  {\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
    Scale=1.0]}
```

The `\defaultfontfeatures` command automatically scales all other fonts in the document to match the height of Palatino.  If you want to match the cap-height instead of the x-height, change `Scale=MatchLowercase` to `Scale=MatchUppercase`.

If you want a matching OpenType math font, load `unicode-math` and add to your preamble:

```
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

Or you might try TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

A good sans-serif companion font for Palatino is Optima, also designed by Hermann Zapf.  This is available *gratis* as URW Classico.  Since the license is not *libre*, you can obtain it from TUG with the [`getnonfreefonts`](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script, or download [the files from CTAN.](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico)  A good matching monospace font is Inconsolata.

To load Rockwell, use a command such as

```
\newfontfamily\Rockwell{Rockwell}
```

If you’re using a different version of the font, such as the one from Monotype, you might wish to specify the files you mean more precisely, such as:

```
\newfontfamily\Rockwell{RockwellStd}[
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Extension = .otf]
```

You could load Light, condensed or ExtraBold here instead.  Add whatever options you need to use its font features.  The `otfinfo` command can tell you what the font supports.

You then would add `\Rockwell` to the formatting of your headers, in whatever package you use for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `titlesec` package to change the heading style, including the font. I don't have the Rockwell font, so I used an alternative one to show the difference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\newfontfamily\headingfont{Rockwell}
\setmainfont{Palatino}
\newfontfamily\chapfont{Herculanum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\huge\chapfont}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter in another font}
My text is in Palatino, though.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put
\usepackage{Palatino}
right after documentclass and it automatically changes to Palatino. The editor I use is Texpad but it should work on any editor for LaTex.

Comment: This will only work with legacy 8-bit fonts, not with `fontspec`.